# Transact-SQL: Join two tables with optional join-attributes in Table 2

Tags: sql-server, join, case, exists

I have problems to define a Transact-SQL (SQL Server) Statement for the following situation:
There are 2 Table 1 and 2, each of them with an ID (primary Key) and 3 Attributes A, B, C. 
In Table 1 all Attributes are mandatory, in Table 2 only A is mandatory.

That means in Table 2 are more or less specific records.

What I want to do is to join these two tables by finding the most specific record of Table 2 for the records of Table 1

[image]
I hope the following picture is an understandable description of the problem:

I have tried Joins following by case statements but always got syntactic errors.

To specify the problem: 
My first approach was to define the join expression with ON Case like this, what of course doesn´t work but:

```
  SELECT * FROM Table T1
     JOIN Table T2 ON CASE
        WHEN T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B=T2.B AND T1.C=T2.C
        THEN T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B=T2.B AND T1.C=T2.C
        WHEN T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B=T2.B AND T1.C!=T2.C
        THEN T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B=T2.B
        WHEN T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B!=T2.B AND T1.C!=T2.C
        THEN T1.A = T2.A
        ELSE 0
```

Therefore I only need an approach, not a whole solution for it.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: What do you mean with "homework"?

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] (especially about homework), hits googling 'stackexhange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Please show some work with justification, explain about the first place you get stuck & ask a specific question about it. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Please read & act  [mcve].

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: Ah ok^^ -> The expected result is shown in the screenshot but I will edit my Question. The second - no, I'm not a student (so no homework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables on the same attributes, while considering the nulls as a wildcard.

Then use the window function `row_number` to get the best match per Table1 ID

```
SELECT ID1, ID2
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.ID AS ID1, t2.ID AS ID2
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY (IIF(t2.AttributeA IS NULL,0,1) + IIF(t2.AttributeB IS NULL,0,1) + IIF(t2.AttributeC IS NULL,0,1)) DESC, t2.AttributeA DESC, t2.AttributeB DESC, t2.AttributeC DESC) AS rn
    FROM Table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2
       ON ((t2.AttributeA = t1.AttributeA OR t2.AttributeA IS NULL) AND
           (t2.AttributeB = t1.AttributeB OR t2.AttributeB IS NULL) AND
           (t2.AttributeC = t1.AttributeC OR t2.AttributeC IS NULL))
) q
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID1;
```

You can test the SQL on rextester [here](http://rextester.com/FKWMHX31089)

Comment: Yes thank you - the Approach after the ON clause was the one I was looking for. And with the right order I get the record of table 2 which is most specified. Thx!

Comment: @MisterD I had a suspicion you would. For such a SQL trick it's sometimes though to find the right google keywords. :)